# Nested component rendering & binding in Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm learning Vue.js and trying to get nested component rendering working.

I've started with the below ([codepen here](http://codepen.io/flowdo/pen/zZxbVR)):

```js
 var buildingComponent = Vue.component('building', {
        template: '#building-component',
  name: 'building-component',
 })

 var roomComponent = Vue.component('room', {
        template: '#room-component',
  name: 'room-component',
  props: ['number'],
 })

 var componentApp = new Vue({
  el: "#components-example",
  data: {
   buildings: [
    {id: 1, name: "144 Orange St", occupants: 5, rooms: [
     {rid: 1, number: "122"},
     {rid: 2, number: "123"},
     {rid: 3, number: "144"},
    ]},

    {id: 2, name: "92 Firth St", occupants: 6, rooms: [
     {rid: 4, number: "155"},
     {rid: 5, number: "344"},
     {rid: 6, number: "343"},
    ]},

    {id: 3, name: "123 Main St", occupants: 2, rooms: [
     {rid: 7, number: "4324"},
     {rid: 8, number: "1244"},
    ]},
   ],
  },
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<!-- Components Example -->
<template id="building-component">
 <div>
  <span>Name: {{ bldg.name }}</span>
  <ul v-if="bldg.rooms">
   <room v-for="room in bldg.rooms" v-bind:room="room" number="room.number"></room>
  </ul>
 </div>
</template>

<template id="room-component">
 <div>
  <li>
   <span>Room {{ room.number }}</span>
  </li>
 </div>
</template>

<p>Components example!</p>
<div id="components-example">
 <ul>
  <li v-for="bldg in buildings" v-bind:bldg="bldg"></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I can't seem to get Vue.js to render properly - I'm a bit confused on what I'm supposed to `v-bind` and where.

I'd of course like whatever is rendered to be 100% reactive to changes to the underlying instance data attributes.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqNJVe

Comment: @CD Can you add that as an answer? It would be helpful to point out what the OP did wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things were missing:

- The components were missing the `template` property.
- The building component was not in use, and the `bldg` property was missing.
- The room component had a `number` property instead of `room`.

See a working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqNJVe